# Using sf in R - what is the best way to add geometry to large point dataset?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sf, r-sp

Disclaimer: I have only started using sf so I might be (hopefully!) missing something obvious here.

I have the [AusGeoid2020](http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/ahdgm/ausgeoid2020) data which consists of 15,454,800 points and some attributes to convert between ellipsoidal heights (i.e. GPS height) and the [AHD](http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/ahdgm/ahd).

Although the file is large (914Mb) it's easy enough to read in:

```
library(plyr)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(sf)

AusGeoid2020 <- read_fwf(
  file = "AUSGeoid2020_20170908_win.dat",
  col_positions = fwf_widths(
    widths = c(3L,9L,2L,2L,3L,7L,2L,3L,3L,7L,10L,10L),
    col_names = c(
      "ID",
      "ellipsoid to AHD separation (m)",
      "Latitude (hem)",
      "Latitude (deg)",
      "Latitude (min)",
      "Latitude (sec)",
      "Longitude (hem)",
      "Longitude (deg)",
      "Longitude (min)",
      "Longitude (sec)",
      "deflection of the vertical (seconds, xi)",
      "deflection of the vertical (seconds, eta)"
    )
  ),
  col_types = cols(
    ID = col_character(),
    `ellipsoid to AHD separation (m)` = col_double(),
    `Latitude (hem)` = col_character(),
    `Latitude (deg)` = col_double(),
    `Latitude (min)` = col_double(),
    `Latitude (sec)` = col_double(),
    `Longitude (hem)` = col_character(),
    `Longitude (deg)` = col_double(),
    `Longitude (min)` = col_double(),
    `Longitude (sec)` = col_double(),
    `deflection of the vertical (seconds, xi)` = col_double(),
    `deflection of the vertical (seconds, eta)` = col_double()
  ),
  skip = 1L
)

AusGeoid2020 <- AusGeoid2020 %>% 
  mutate(
    Latitude = `Latitude (deg)` + (`Latitude (min)`/60) + (`Latitude (sec)`/3600),
    Latitude = case_when(
      `Latitude (hem)` == "S" ~ -1 * Latitude,
      TRUE ~ Latitude
    ),
    Longitude = `Longitude (deg)` + (`Longitude (min)`/60) + (`Longitude (sec)`/3600),
    Longitude = case_when(
      `Longitude (hem)` == "W" ~ -1 * Longitude,
      TRUE ~ Longitude
    )
  ) %>% 
  select(
    ID,
    `ellipsoid to AHD separation (m)`,
    Latitude,
    Longitude,
    `deflection of the vertical (seconds, xi)`,
    `deflection of the vertical (seconds, eta)`
  )
```

My question is: what is the best way to add geometry to this large data frame? I believe the function I want is `st_point()` which is not vectorised, so I have resorted to using `alply()` from {plyr} to create the geometry column, but this is *very* resource intensive which makes me think there must be a better way.

```
st_geometry(AusGeoid2020) <- st_sfc(
  alply(AusGeoid2020, 1, function(row) {
    st_point(x = c(row$Longitude, row$Latitude), dim = "XY")
  }),
  crs = 7844L
)
```

This takes a very long time. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: You could use `Map`, e.g. `st_sfc(Map(function(lat, lon) st_point(c(lon, lat), dim = 'XY'), lat = AusGeoid2020$Latitude, lon = AusGeoid2020$Longitude), crs = 7844L)` to cut off some overhead, but at this size it will still take a while. You could use `st_multipoint` if the metadata that goes with the points is duplicative (or you don't care about it), which would be faster.

Comment: Hi Edward @alistaire, I didn't mean to imply that I was concerned about `alply()`, as such. I'm sure it's very efficient and, if I had the energy, I'd do some benchmarking to compare it with `Map()` - I would expect to see very little difference. My issue is with having to map the function in the first place. I guess I am assuming there is a way the designers of `sf` intended for this operation to be carried out that was a bit more efficient. I haven't yet figured out the difference between point and multipoint - do you have any pointers? (ha!) The attributes in the dataframe *are* significant

Comment: plyr generally fares very poorly when it comes to speed; I ran a quick benchmark and it was 2 orders of magnitude slower than `Map` (median 20.5s vs 0.13s). Multipoint is a different geometry that holds multiple points in a single simple feature. It can work nicely if your data is grouped such that you care about metadata on the group more than each individual point, e.g. for a dataset of street signs, the group might be the sign type, and the geometry a multipoint of all the locations of that sign type (in a single simple feature and therefore row).

Comment: @alistaire Wow, if anything I would have expected plyr to have the better performance because it was implemented more recently. I do tend to use plyr a lot - it's my go-to when I'm working with non-data.frame objects - which is quite often - and it makes it very easy to parallelise across the 24 cores of my server. Thanks for making me realise I need to question my assumptions more often!

Comment: plyr just hasn't been worked on that much since it's been supplanted by dplyr and purrr, and it always prioritized UI over speed, afaik. `parallel::mclapply` and `mcMap` are pretty easy to use too, though, and there's [future](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future) and [furrr](https://davisvaughan.github.io/furrr/) if you want/need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `st_as_sf` as follows. The default setting would remove the columns with coordinate information (in this case, `Longitude` and `Latitude`). If you want to keep those columns, set `remove = FALSE`.

```
AusGeoid2020_sf <- AusGeoid2020 %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 7844L, remove = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you @www! I used both methods and the resulting objects were `identical()`. `st_as_sf()` is very, very fast - clearly this is what I was after.